# making the text to align with the second level bullet above

Tags: beamer, align

```
\subsection{Previous Studies}
\frame[label=exampleframe]{
\frametitle{Previous Studies}

\begin{itemize}
\item There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies
\addtolength{\itemindent}{1cm} \item  There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies
\item There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies
\item There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies
\item stigma effects (Lockwood 1991, Omori 1997, Biewen and Steffes 2009)
\end{itemize}
}
```

This is my code and it shows like this:
![enter image description here][2]

From the 2nd-5th bullet I want them to be indented more, but I do not not want the following text to be sticking outside the bullet like this. For the first level bullet, the text is "automatically"(?) neatly aligned with the bullet above. Could someone tell me how to do the same for the rest of the bullets? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Have you considered nesting the itemize environment? `\begin{itemize}\item test \begin{itemize} \item test 2 \end{itemize} \end{itemize}`

Answer (score 1):

To turn my comment into an answer, you should use nested `itemize` environments:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Previous Studies}
\frame[label=exampleframe]{
\frametitle{Previous Studies}

\begin{itemize}
    \item There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies
    \begin{itemize} 
        \item  There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies
    \end{itemize}
    \item There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies
    \item There are many studies There are many studies There are many studies
    \item stigma effects (Lockwood 1991, Omori 1997, Biewen and Steffes 2009)
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```